# Jest testing the same promise response in different types each time

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

How do I properly test the same promise response which can be in different type ?

For example, when fetching a collection of items from Cloud Firestore database, response is in a type of an array, but there is a way to interact with a response as it was in a type of an object. Here is the code:

```
// ...
await Database.collection('products').select('published').get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => { // <---- HERE snapshot IS AN ARRAY
    if (doc.data().published) {
      // ...
    }
  })
  console.log(snapshot.docs.length) // <---- HERE snapshot IS AN OBJECT. HOW ?
  console.log(snapshot.size) // IT'S THE SAME AS snapshot.docs.length
})
// ...
```

I'm trying to test it by returning a value differently after each call, but it's now working, I'm getting an error:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`:

```
jest.doMock('@google-cloud/firestore', () => class {
  constructor () {
    this.collection = jest.fn().mockImplementation((collectionName) => {
      if (collectionName === 'products') {
        return {
          select: () => ({
            get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([ // <--- AN ARRAY
              {
                data: () => {
                  return {
                    published: false
                  }
                }
              }
            ]).mockResolvedValueOnce({ // <---- AN OBJECT
              docs: () => []
            })
          }),
          limit: () => ({ get: async () => ({ empty: true }) })
        }
      }
    })
  }
})
```

What's wrong here ? What should I use among all those mockings ?:

- `mockImplementation`
- `mockImplementationOnce`
- `mockResolvedValue`
- `mockResolvedValueOnce`
- `mockReturnValue`
- `mockReturnValueOnce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use class to create test doubles. It makes things complicated. Just use the JS plain object data type - `Array` to make the query snapshot of firestore. Use `Object` to make the query document snapshot.

You can add custom properties to the JS array such as `snapshot.docs` and `snapshot.size`.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

export async function main() {
  const Database = new Firestore();
  await Database.collection('products')
    .select('published')
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.data().published) {
          console.log(doc.data());
        }
      });
      console.log(snapshot.docs.length);
      console.log(snapshot.size);
    });
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
describe('71058297', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
  });
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const mDocument1 = { data: jest.fn(() => ({ published: true, name: 'steam deck' })) };
    const mQuerySnapshot: any = [mDocument1];
    mQuerySnapshot.docs = mQuerySnapshot;
    mQuerySnapshot.size = mQuerySnapshot.docs.length;
    const mFirestore = {
      collection: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      get: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mQuerySnapshot),
    };
    const MockFireStore = jest.fn(() => mFirestore);
    jest.doMock('@google-cloud/firestore', () => ({ Firestore: MockFireStore }));
    const { main } = require('./');
    await main();
    expect(MockFireStore).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mFirestore.collection).toBeCalledWith('products');
    expect(mFirestore.select).toBeCalledWith('published');
    expect(mFirestore.get).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mDocument1.data).toBeCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71058297/index.test.ts
  71058297
    ✓ should pass (24 ms)

  console.log
    { published: true, name: 'steam deck' }

      at stackoverflow/71058297/index.ts:33:17
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

  console.log
    1

      at stackoverflow/71058297/index.ts:36:13

  console.log
    1

      at stackoverflow/71058297/index.ts:37:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.595 s, estimated 2 s
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! If there is any special website where I can learn more about jest mocking please share the link. I've never seen this approach you are using, so simple without complicated mockings.